# Origin of Berge's (Weak) Perfect Graph Conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory

In an [account of his thought process](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X0026X/1-s2.0-S0012365X96001616/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCZa1lHRy1C7HrY69OBKPge8ABmdQJK%2FlBEkgRO5jIdFwIhAK8hPuWsTDcwq4HX0gmSGCG%2FrpWvam1SHjgsDUWp41yWKtIECHgQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgziPZAgfGAyFuPelHEqrwTKgqfwWLOiVNC7HMs9zhjaGa1MTiqqmMNOJjO3IAem3wXRCCkjCIxHlJXndGYxO1H9BFkFuS%2Bbv40Izo5YNPvmM1kBhn%2Fd8vIknVgdRmjUxJ7LlsEGJtbZOb1lKrlhKxHPSv1i0bs1T%2BLqAkcm6Evo75EI77eE0zvlIGqFhX%2BRfa31m5ErRJrB%2Fa8d22ZlrnXUQopTgCIxdCDLfvYUlhjjyzwZ5NO4xnmfT6Z2fQIMmv5Lt426kB4QO0KVFT0rX2E9S2z0a1LVyt7IqbxYsw5kmtJncjpTqSl01VsFK9Dk0teRBgZ082RBPDDGBNXOxGn6pCBxTVSVa5Q4bmWBhhcWVKWvxek1QsIzYXgBJLcqUT1NmD2mVuGORdfbE3C1Tkqpq20zipZel%2FlVEySl%2Bw%2Be2QURY0Yozr7WlVlmav9JYcapTQkf26Pl40G3aEPst50OgzZxDqAKePyPglTImF8vifRV6xoczYngMZrQNUoElelKO4DnulbFY9kCkLeTsl5349U8fAeL1b7sWWvvMSk8yCCVsmq9EgWlH0FDsU35zhkd%2BfJstZOrFH7v9txab1CN5h0Swulzm4Yd5hwLj2Ugbs6Y%2Fe8nv2vgpSoBcQeheIDTpTPEBWuGkS6m9prEsT%2BsqIKTVrexpCTypEfAss1ELKBbucGaPdDMCpn%2FIq9WfeDVjdjgLdk8xgm2XEY0wVYy%2Fo97TyWphnhqS8EzKjYRfGD5HXOM5twtuldX4JRPMOrghpYGOqgBvWkf4EQFKkULHeaGpLiMJGTRkjhbrGa3gyyQS1vAGgNoeVmV45X5XunJoP6InODIJPrVkeWt4sQKAo35qX04oDPi4424hS1nWhmwN2mEcoNWWVEHl6c0HcK%2BQcJwPEcwJ24lisMVLTP8bEUo6Ina0nwfsKEa%2FhupuPfZjSdFtE6UMHYWYxwfJ9J5YgTiGgmwqyxVERUlD8a1cwmbYv6516ODm2kSv3ab&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220703T154507Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYURYH6THF%2F20220703%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=67024588b244a9f01d7002d92b837b0e85329b6c84bf8560744c14d4dfa6089f&hash=5ca22e7e6e33d7dc12bbe5b3a06620b8b8d24ff05eea16ae238b91158182bd9a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0012365X96001616&tid=spdf-84addc41-ab04-48b3-a4aa-e18622d21edc&sid=b1970acc3e54c74dd169a9013dcbc60991cagxrqb&type=client&ua=585d50550706555254&rr=7250bf150a869042) (refer p. 3) leading up to the perfect graph conjecture (which I'm preparing a seminar talk on), C. Berge states what seems to be a crucial step:

> (1) a graph $G$ is in Class 1 if $\phi(G) = \alpha(G)$

with the

stability number $\alpha (G)$ the cardinality of the largest subset $S$ of vertices in $G$ such that no vertices are adjacent

[zero-error capacity $\phi (G)$](https://staff.science.uva.nl/c.schaffner/courses/infcom/2014/Shannon_zeroerror.pdf) (which I'm only starting to grasp);

> (4) a graph $G$ is in Class 4 if $G$ contains no induced $C_{2k+i}$, the odd cycle of length
> $2k + 1 \geq 5$ (called odd hole) and no induced complement of an odd hole (called odd antihole).

> I asked: Is it true that every graph in Class 4 is also in Class 1? This conjecture, somewhat weaker than the Perfect Graph Conjecture, was motivated by the remark that for the most usual channels, the graphs representing the possible confusions between a set of signals (in particular the interval graphs) have no odd holes and no odd antiholes, and are optimal in the sense of Shannon.

*My questions are*

1. What channels are 'most usual'? Channels in the sense of physical wires transmitting a signal? Why would one suppose these channels allow to derive a universal fact about graphs?
2. 'Confusions between a set of signals' are some kind of interference? 'Graphs representing the possible confusions' would have nodes where these wires touch?